# When simulating verilog output using Icarus, is there a way to include FPGA hardware features such as RAM in the simulation?

Tags: simulation, fpga, icarus

I'm new to FPGA, and have started out with an iceBreaker board using the ICE40UP5K chip. I'm aiming to make a LED display driver, driving something similar to HUB75 used on popular display modules.

I've been able to simulate waveform generation, and view it in GtkWave using the tutorial here:
https://brng.dev/blog/technical/tutorial/2019/05/11/icarus_gtkwave/

My next steps involve making use of the RAM banks inside of the ICE40UP5K. Is there some way to include the existence of this RAM in my simulation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course - there is a library of simulated ICE40 cells included in Yosys: https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/blob/master/techlibs/ice40/cells_sim.v